# Activerecord/PSQL determine if record is within top 100 of order on many columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm attempting to have a leaderboard-esque platform that utilizes ruby on rails for the backend. I'm working with a postgres database. My user table has many columns that resemble statistics for this leaderboard. My goal is to determine if a user exists within the top 100 of any column, and return those columns. Here is my current code that accomplishes the task, albeit poorly

```rb
def check_user(user)
  User.column_names.filter do |name|
    User.all.order("#{name} DESC").limit(100).index(user)
  end
end
```

While this works and gives the correct result, the issue is that each query is executed separately. In my current setup there are roughly 4500 columns I need to check, resulting in 4500+ queries made to the database. Is there any way to accomplish this task without making each check and individual database query? Or any other methods to overall speed up the process

My current schema looks something like this.

```rb
create_table "users" do |t|

end

create_table "weapon_stats" do |t|
  t.belongs_to :user

  t.integer :weapon_kills_ak47
  t.integer :weapon_shots_ak47
  t.integer :weapon_uses_ak47
  t.integer :weapon_hits_ak47
  ...
end

create_table "player_stats" do |t|
  t.belongs_to :user

  t.integer :character_used_a
  t.integer :character_used_b
  t.integer :character_used_c
  ...
end

create_table "misc_stats" do |t|
  t.belongs_to :user

  t.integer :mission_completed_a
  t.integer :mission_completed_b
  t.integer :mission_completed_c
  ...
end
```

All columns are integers, ranging from 0 to the 32bit signed int limit, and there are roughly 4500 individual statistics to track. The database has roughly 250,000 users, and I would not expect it to exceed 1M-2M.

Outside of this specific case, I need to be able to display a top 100 for each individual stat. Each user also needs to be somewhat easily updatable without too much overhead.

All code is here if any more information is necessary https://github.com/0lafe/payday2Charts

Comment: "4500 columns" . Might want to rethink this part of the design, not sure there is an efficient way to handle what you are suggesting. Best bet might be to precalculate the 100th position and store it in a table. How often does the data change?

Comment: Yeah haha, unfortunately there are ~4500 individual stats to keep track of, so I couldn't really figure out a better schema. It's technically 3 different tables linked to the user, as postgres seems to have a ~1600 column limit per table haha

I was worried I'd need to cache the results somehow. The data is (sort of) always changing, so it's not an ideal solution, but it's much better than nothing. I haven't done a ton of persistent data storage in memory. Would redis be a good solution for this? Thanks for the tip

Comment: Can you post more information about your tables and models? We can help suggest a better ORM or give suggestions on how to separate your data.

Comment: Absolutely. I updated the post with the rough schema, and a link to the repo. The models are mostly just linking tables that belong to each other, and attempting to do what I'm asking for help on.

Comment: Tracking the top 100 of each stat might be a better approach as suggested. There are several approaches to this, but one way would be a table of *(indexed)* stat names => value, user ID might be sufficient for now *(particularly if only a few stats change at once)*, combined w/ MIN/MAX functions to see if something needs to be updated. *(Caveat: I haven't thought this through completely at all.)*

Answer (score 1):

This is not necessarily an answer but too long for a comment.

I would consider a redesign of the application into

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_stats 
end

# name (e.g. player, weapon, mission)
class StatCategory < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :stats
end 

# name, stat_category_id 
class Stat < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :stat_category 
end 

# user_id, stat_id, stat_value
class UserStat < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :stat
end
```

This simplifies the structure while making it readily extensible.

Additionally it simplifies querying or caching "leaderboards" via:
**JOINABLE QUERY**

```
SELECT 
  ranked_stats.*
FROM 
(
SELECT
  user_stats.*,
  ROW_NUMBER () OVER(PARTITION BY stat_id ORDER BY stat_value DESC) As position
FROM 
  user_stats
) As ranked_stats
WHERE 
  ranked_stats.position <= 100
```

or **CACHE VALUES**

```
SELECT 
  ranked_stats.stat_id,
  MIN(ranked_stats.stat_value) AS min_value,
  MAX(ranked_stats.stat_value) AS max_value
FROM 
(
SELECT
  user_stats.stat_id,
  user_stats.stat_value,
  ROW_NUMBER () OVER(PARTITION BY stat_id ORDER BY stat_value DESC) As position
FROM 
  user_stats
) As ranked_stats
WHERE 
  ranked_stats.position <= 100
GROUP BY 
  ranked_stats.stat_id
```

**Note:** These are just recommendations and have not been fully vetted in your production environment or at scale in any way